# Paper.js build error: env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, bash, build

I can't seem to run the build.sh script to get started with paper.js.

From within the build folder i get:
env: node: No such file or directory

Strangely, I can run it from outside the build folder using:
./build/build.sh

but get another path related error:
./build/build.sh: line 37: ./preprocess.sh: No such file or directory

I'm assuming this is a general issue with running bash scripts.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The script calls [`build/prepro.js`](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/master/build/prepro.js), which runs in node.js (see the first line: `#!/usr/bin/env node`), but you seem to not have it installed (or at least it's not found by `env`).

Try installing node.js, or making it available to `env`, so the build script will work.